# Wordpress - insert HTML code with different CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a wordpress site and I got an HTML for the homepage, buy when I put the the whole HTML code in Wordpress it doesn't show the page correctly
So I want that wordpress charges this page independenly of the theme CSS, how can I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, are you just trying to put he html into wordpress? If so, it does not work like that. You may want to have a look at the wordpress codex to find out how it works at https://codex.wordpress.org/. If not, please provide some example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theme style.css is included by default by the wordpress by wp_head() function. Before you end you HEAD tag add this function.

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

If you want to add additional stylesheets then use this function in your functions.php file.

```
function additional_custom_styles() {

    /*Enqueue The Styles*/
    wp_enqueue_style( 'themename', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'additional_custom_styles' );
```